# Java: How to merge multiple excel file (.xlsx) file which has same number of columns into one single Excel file

Tags: java, excel, merge, zip, multiple-columns

I am new to java and I am trying to extract files from password protected zip file which contains excel sheet and merge it into one single Excel file.

I am able to extract all the zip files in an directory but I am not sure how to merge the multiple excel all of which have  same columns into one.
All the excel sheets have same number of columns and name of the column is same for all I need to merge into single excel sheet with one single header.

Unzipping password protected zip file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.FileHeader;

public class SamExtraction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final FileNameExtensionFilter extensionFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("N/A", "zip");
        //Folder where zip file is present
        final File file = new File("C:/Users/Desktop/ZipFile");
        for (final File child : file.listFiles()) {
            try {
                ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(child);
                if (extensionFilter.accept(child)) {
                    if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
                        //Your ZIP password
                        zipFile.setPassword("MYPASS!");
                    }
                    List fileHeaderList = zipFile.getFileHeaders();

                    for (int i = 0; i < fileHeaderList.size(); i++) {
                        FileHeader fileHeader = (FileHeader) fileHeaderList.get(i);
                        //Path where you want to Extract
                        zipFile.extractFile(fileHeader, "C:/Users/Desktop/ZipFile");
                        System.out.println("Extracted");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Please Try Again");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to use [POI](https://poi.apache.org/) - unless you want to read and understand the [OOXML spec](http://officeopenxml.com/) and implement an Excel library yourself.

Comment: Does this have to be in Java? Its the sort of thing that is pretty easy to write as an Excel macro.

Comment: Hi Matt Helliwell, Thanks for the response. Since I have written the first part of the program(Extraction of zip file) in java I want to continue it in java and it will be a series of execution Extract ZIP File-> Merge all excel file-> Remove duplicates -> Order the column in specified format.

Comment: @matthelliwell is right. Your zip extraction code is nothing that you'd want to keep anyway - using an Excel macro would be much easier if that's the only thing you want to do. Using POI, you would discard the zip extraction code too, and the POI handle manipulating the excel files.

Comment: Is there anyway through which I can integrate the VBA code to java so that I can include everything in single program.